# I'm building a database in unlimited version but I think i'm doing this wrong

Tags: managed-package, database, developer, unmanaged-package

I think I did this wrong?  Can someone advice me?

I basically paid a $250 month unlimited service to build a database but I would like to sell it on appexchange.  So as I build, I realized that I need my database managed so no one can get the codes I'm using.  Also, I didnt know that I could just get a free developer account.  Is it possible to get what i've done and import them to a new developer site?  Or can I just upgrade my unlimted edition account?

I have this error...

**Your organization is configured to create unmanaged packages only. Unmanaged packages are not upgradeable.
To create a managed package, you must be using Developer Edition. Sign up for Developer Edition**

ultimately, this is what I want to do... build a database and sell it in app exchange.

what should my route be?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Will the app that you are selling contain data or is it just configuration and code?

Comment: it will be blank data but will help clients upload their data free service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create a free Developer Account

   - Then you can create a namespace and a managed package.
   - Link to info on managed packages: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=enabling_managed_packages.htm&language=en
2. Use an IDE to migrate the metadata for your objects / field / code to the new DE account
3. Talk to your AE to see what they can do with your contract with SF if anything

Comment: Thanks so much for this.  

I really dont mind paying the monthly.  I just want to make sure I meet deadline.

Comment: @NinjaKing - If it answers your question to your satisfaction please mark it as answered

Answer (score 2):

You need to talk to your AE, ASAP.

In order to list an app on the AppExchange (or in order to do OEM sales, which it sounds like is what you really want to do here) you need to join the partner program, sign a partner contract with SFDC, get an AppExchange listing, and go through security review.

This is a many month process. You want to start it soon.

Comment: wow.  Well I have a dealine of the project by Feb and so I hope we have it up and running in the AppExchange already.

Comment: Yup, you'll need to get enrolled in either the ISVForce or Force.com Embedded Partner Programs, finish your app, and then submit it for review before you are granted a listing. The review process takes 6-8 weeks, assuming you pass on the first try, and costs $2700.